# Observable onErrorReturn not firing in production, but works in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, error-handling, rx-java, observable

I currently have an issue with a piece of code where an .onErrorReturn statements fires as expected when running my unit tests, but not in production.

The code snippet looks like this:

```
return restApiAdapter.createPosition(createPositionRequest)
    .flatMap(dealReference -> restApiAdapter.getDealConfirmationObservable(dealReference.getValue())
        .retryWhen(new RetryWithDelay(3, 1500))
        .map(dealConfirmationResponse -> buyConfirmationHandler(dealConfirmationResponse, createPositionRequest.getDirection(), tradeParams))
    )
    .onErrorReturn(e -> {
                LOG.debug("Broker buy failed, returning error value {}", ZorroReturnValues.BROKER_BUY_FAIL.getValue());
                return ZorroReturnValues.BROKER_BUY_FAIL.getValue();
    })
    .blockingSingle();
```

Basically the flatMap sometimes returns an exception, which I want to retry on. After retrying three times, I want the onErrorReturn to fire and return an error value. Just to give an idea, this is the output from the unit test (retryWhen works as expected, onErrorReturn fires)

```
[RxComputationThreadPool-1] DEBUG c.danlind.igz.adapter.RestApiAdapter - Attempting to get confirmation for dealReference TestDealReference
[RxComputationThreadPool-1] WARN  c.danlind.igz.adapter.RestApiAdapter - Order with deal id TestDealId was rejected with reason code ATTACHED_ORDER_LEVEL_ERROR
[RxComputationThreadPool-1] DEBUG com.danlind.igz.misc.RetryWithDelay - Retry 1 of 3
[RxComputationThreadPool-2] DEBUG c.danlind.igz.adapter.RestApiAdapter - Attempting to get confirmation for dealReference TestDealReference
[RxComputationThreadPool-2] WARN  c.danlind.igz.adapter.RestApiAdapter - Order with deal id TestDealId was rejected with reason code ATTACHED_ORDER_LEVEL_ERROR
[RxComputationThreadPool-2] DEBUG com.danlind.igz.misc.RetryWithDelay - Retry 2 of 3
[RxComputationThreadPool-3] DEBUG c.danlind.igz.adapter.RestApiAdapter - Attempting to get confirmation for dealReference TestDealReference
[RxComputationThreadPool-3] WARN  c.danlind.igz.adapter.RestApiAdapter - Order with deal id TestDealId was rejected with reason code ATTACHED_ORDER_LEVEL_ERROR
[RxComputationThreadPool-3] DEBUG com.danlind.igz.misc.RetryWithDelay - Max retries exceeded, passing error downstream
[RxComputationThreadPool-3] DEBUG com.danlind.igz.brokerapi.BrokerBuy - Broker buy failed, returning error value 0
```

But in production, when an exception is thrown, all I get is this:

```
[RxComputationThreadPool-1] DEBUG c.danlind.igz.adapter.RestApiAdapter - Attempting to get confirmation for dealReference 94ZY4P5RMP244TP
[RxComputationThreadPool-1] WARN  c.danlind.igz.adapter.RestApiAdapter - Order with deal id DIAAAABB9R4L4AM was rejected with reason code ATTACHED_ORDER_LEVEL_ERROR
[RxComputationThreadPool-1] DEBUG com.danlind.igz.misc.RetryWithDelay - Retry 1 of 3
[RxComputationThreadPool-1] DEBUG c.danlind.igz.adapter.RestApiAdapter - Attempting to get confirmation for dealReference 94ZY4P5RMP244TP
[RxComputationThreadPool-1] WARN  c.danlind.igz.adapter.RestApiAdapter - Order with deal id DIAAAABB9R4L4AM was rejected with reason code ATTACHED_ORDER_LEVEL_ERROR
[RxComputationThreadPool-1] DEBUG com.danlind.igz.misc.RetryWithDelay - Retry 2 of 3
[RxComputationThreadPool-1] DEBUG c.danlind.igz.adapter.RestApiAdapter - Attempting to get confirmation for dealReference 94ZY4P5RMP244TP
[RxComputationThreadPool-1] WARN  c.danlind.igz.adapter.RestApiAdapter - Order with deal id DIAAAABB9R4L4AM was rejected with reason code ATTACHED_ORDER_LEVEL_ERROR
[RxComputationThreadPool-1] DEBUG com.danlind.igz.misc.RetryWithDelay - Max retries exceeded, passing error downstream
```

I just can't figure out why my unit test is working as expected, but the production system is not. What am I missing?

RetryWithDelay code:

```
public class RetryWithDelay implements Function<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>> {
    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RetryWithDelay.class);
    private final int maxRetries;
    private final int retryDelayMillis;
    private int retryCount;

    public RetryWithDelay(final int maxRetries, final int retryDelayMillis) {
        this.maxRetries = maxRetries;
        this.retryDelayMillis = retryDelayMillis;
        this.retryCount = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<?> apply(final Observable<? extends Throwable> attempts) {
        return attempts
            .flatMap(new Function<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<?> apply(final Throwable throwable) {
                    if (++retryCount < maxRetries) {
                        LOG.debug("Retry {} of {}", retryCount, maxRetries);
                        // When this Observable calls onNext, the original
                        // Observable will be retried (i.e. re-subscribed).
                        return Observable.timer(retryDelayMillis,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    }

                    LOG.debug("Max retries exceeded, passing error downstream");

                    // Max retries hit. Just pass the error along.
                    return Observable.error(throwable);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Which exact RxJava version are you using? Could you verify that you have the same version in both production and test?

Comment: I'm running 2.0.6, same in both test and production

Comment: Do you have a single core restriction in production?

Comment: Never occurred to me, but yes. Running on a AWS EC2 micro instance which only has 1 core.

Comment: When you have blocking like your code, it may lead to same pool deadlock.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try running on a multi core server and see if the problem goes away!

Comment: Btw, can I somehow rewrite this code to make it work even with a single core restriction?

Comment: Either use `Scheduler.io()` that gets you multiple threads or redesign your code to not block by extending the reach of the `Observable`.

Comment: Will look at Schedulers.io then, calling client can not handle async

Comment: I thought that .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) would solve this, but it doesn't. I'm still seeing the same issue as described above. Any hints?

Comment: Do you have other uses of `Schedulers.computation()`? You can replace the computation scheduler with the single scheduler via RxJavaPlugins and see if your code hangs in dev (also showing where).

Comment: You can also use the [RxJavaPlugins.setFailOnNonBlockingScheduler](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/plugins/RxJavaPlugins.html#setFailOnNonBlockingScheduler(boolean)) to trigger failure if a blocking call is executed on the computation scheduler.

Comment: I'm not using Schedulers.computation() anywhere (not explicitly atleast), but Schedulers.io() is used a bunch

Comment: I tried both of the above, the unit test still passes without problems.

Comment: Last idea: see if the error gets routed to the global handler by hooking RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler. Without the full and standalone code, I have no idea what could be the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that as well. This is actually from an open source project, the entire code is available here https://github.com/dan-lind/igzplugin (specific example from BrokerBuy)